# Microsoft Graph Endpoint for the German Cloud

Tags: azure, cloud, microsoft-graph-api

The article https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/deployments mentions the sovereign (national) cloud deployment in China only at the moment. What's the story for Germany?

The reason for asking is that there are AAD Login / AAD Graph endpoints specific to the German Cloud (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuregermany/2016/08/18/endpoints-in-microsoft-cloud-germany/, and verified), so there must be one for Microsoft Graph too, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed response.  We just updated our documentation.  Please see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/deployments.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Just made an update to the answer.  Let us know if you have any issues using the German national cloud.